# how solve vue js not detected in vue dev tools?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-devtools

hi i have this error in dev tools in vue3
and you can say icon devtools is off in my app tabs on chrome

[image]

I go to this extension and turn on Allow access to file URLs , add  `app.config.silent = true` in main.js and set   `"persistent": true,` in manifest.json of vue devtools and it didnt work yet!

do you know what I should do for solve that?

Comment: use this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg?hl=en
the current vue js dev tools does not support vue 3

Comment: thank you now it solved but I have another problem: you can see devtools is on but vue 

do you know what should i do?

Comment: have you tried close and open the browser again?

Comment: @Mic Fung, reopening the console should be enough.

Comment: @wittgenstein just provide a straight forward way for him to make it works. I think he solved it and should be able to see the dev tools already.